# How to fetch camera based and media based images/videos separately to display in collection view in iOS device

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, alassetslibrary, photokit

I am developing a chat app. In my app when I click attachement button, two options should come.

1) images/videos captured by the device camera(not capturing image at that time. Fetch images taken by the camera that is stored in the device)

2) images/videos downloaded from the web or other medias

Is there any way to fetch images/videos according to the above given criteria preferably using assets library

Answer (score 0):

```
class YourController :  UIViewController,UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate,UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate
{    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    func takePhotoByGalleryOrCamera(){

        //MAark Take picture from gallery and camera 
        //image picker controller to use take image 
        // uialert controller to make action

        let imageController = UIImagePickerController()
        imageController.editing = false
        imageController.delegate = self;

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "Profile Image Selctor", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)


        let libButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Select photo from library", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (alert) -> Void in
            imageController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
            self.presentViewController(imageController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }


        if(UIImagePickerController .isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera)){
            let cameraButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Take a picture", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (alert) -> Void in
                print("Take Photo")
                imageController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
                self.presentViewController(imageController, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }
            alert.addAction(cameraButton)
        } else {
            print("Camera not available")

        }
        let cancelButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel) { (alert) -> Void in
            print("Cancel Pressed")
        }

        alert.addAction(libButton)
        alert.addAction(cancelButton)

        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Pad {

            alert.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover;
            //        alert.transitioningDelegate = self;
            alert.popoverPresentationController!.sourceView = self.view;
            alert.popoverPresentationController!.sourceRect = CGRectMake(0, SizeUtil.screenHeight(), SizeUtil.screenWidth(), SizeUtil.screenHeight()*0.4)
            alert.popoverPresentationController!.delegate = self;

            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
           self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }



    }

    func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {

        return UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
    }


    //image picker Delegate
    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

        let header = profileTableView.headerViewForSection(0) as! ProfileHeaderView
        header.btnImage.setImage(image, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        _userProfileImage = image

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not good at swift. What I understood from your code is device camera is accessed for taking pics. But I want the images taken by the camera earlier that is stored in the device and the images from media as two different entities like in android phones. Is that possible?

Comment: you can only use pick by gallery if you want like android you need to use filemanager http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_Files_in_Swift_on_iOS_8